# Nginx non-www not redirecting

Tags: nginx

I am a total noob when it comes to servers but I am learning. I got this Nginx server block that is working as we would like it to do. The only thing that goes wrong is that when someone goes to the url **mysite.nl** instead of **https://mysite.nl** or **https://www.mysite.nl**, they will get an error page saying the page is insecure.

I tried looking on Google and Stackoverflow for examples but I cannot get them to work either.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this? my server block is displayed below. The top part should redirect any non-www to www but I think it is not working. So what I want is when someone goes to **mysite.nl** they will end up at **https://www.mysite.nl**.

Hope someone can help me out.

````
server {                                                                                                                                               
        server_name mysite.nl;                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                       
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                       
        return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.nl$request_uri;                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                       
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.nl-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot                                         
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.nl-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot                                       
}                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                       
server {                                                                                                                                               
        root /var/www/mysite.nl/;                                                                                                        
        index index.html index.htm index.php;                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                       
        server_name *.mysite.nl;                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                       
        location / {                                                                                                                                   
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3009/;                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                       
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;                                                    
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;                                                                                                               
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;                                                                                                     
        add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                       
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                       
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.nl-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot                                         
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.nl-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot                                       
}                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                       
server {                                                                                                                                               
        root /var/www/mysite.nl/;                                                                                                        
        index index.html index.htm index.php;                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                       
        server_name mysite.nl;                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                       
        location / {                                                                                                                                   
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3009/;                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                       
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;                                                    
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;                                                                                                               
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;                                                                                                     
        add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                       
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                       
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.nl-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot                                         
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.nl-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot                                       
}                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                       
server {                                                                                                                                               
        if ($host = www.mysite.nl) {                                                                                                     
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                                                                  
        } # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                       
        if ($host = mysite.nl) {                                                                                                         
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;                                                                                                  
        } # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                       
        server_name mysite.nl www.mysite.nl;                                                                               
        listen 80;                                                                                                                                     
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # managed by Certbot                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                      ```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your config. Namely that you have 2 server blocks using the same sever_name so that's going to cause odd behavior. Recommend using a single server block. Also, the return blocks at the bottom are kind of broken and may be adding to the confusion.

You could just have the cert issued with all the names you're going to access the server with.

One option is to use docker + nginx-proxy + acme-companion to handle all the heavy lifting. https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy and https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion